# Is there a way to adjust the build order of a package in catkin (pcl)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to build ros from source.  while attempting to link pcl_example_extract_clusters_normals I get the error:

/usr/bin/ld cannot find -lpcl_visualization

It looks like visualization has not yet been built and am guessing there is a build order issue.

Alternatively, is there a safe way to make and install a sub-component?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56264/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-build-order-of-a-package-in-catkin-(pcl)?/) by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a default catkin workspace layout (what catkin-make creates), configuration order is done by the build_depend tags in the package.xml, and build ordering can be achieved using add_dependencies() in CMakeLists.txt across packages. So in your case you'd have to find out the exact cmake target name of the pcl_visualization library and use that.

You can go into the build folder and type "make " and press tab to get a list of all targets, this can sometimes be the quicker way to find the name of a target. There should be a command for this as well, if someone knows please add a comment.

In isolated workspaces (what catkin_make_isolated creates), build order is achived using the build_depend tags in the package.xml.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on 2013-02-27**:
KruseT

Thank you very much - that did the trick.  I had to add visualization to the SUBSYS_DEPS in .../examples/CMakeLists.txt file and start over.